# md-char-count not updating in md-input-container

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, angular-material

Consider the following simple md-input-container with textarea inside:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <textarea aria-label="tt" ng-model="obj.prop" md-maxlength="250" rows="5"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

When i update `obj.prop` in my controller, the text is changed (therefore i should call `$scope.$evalAsync()` too). However, the `md-char-count` is still not updated. In order it to be updated, user will click on text-area and change it. Only then it is being changed.

I think its a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1983) but is there any improvements or is there a -at least- a workaround to this problem?

Here you find [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adxJgX?editors=1111)

*ps(if needed):angular-material version 1.0.1 & angular 1.4.5*

Comment: A codepen demo will be needed too....

Comment: @RayonDabre its added.

Comment: When value is updated in controller and How ? How to reproduce it ?

Comment: just update the value assigned to text-area in console. when you update by `$scope.$evalAsync()`, it will update the text but not the md-char-count

Comment: This look typical bug..Would suggest you add it as a bug and wait for the patch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by override - md-maxlength directive.
Try this codepen - http://codepen.io/himvins/pen/JEgyOK?editors=1010

Function for overriding md-maxlength:

```
function override_mdMaxlength($provide) {
    $provide.decorator(
        'mdMaxlengthDirective',
        function($delegate) {
            var mdMaxlength = $delegate[0];
            var link = mdMaxlength.link;
            mdMaxlength.compile = function() {
                //Line 18 to 64: Code of md-maxlength directive. Change in line 62
                return function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
                    var maxlength;
                    var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
                    var containerCtrl = ctrls[1];
                    var charCountEl = angular.element('<div class="md-char-counter">');

                    attr.$set('ngTrim', 'false');
                    containerCtrl.element.append(charCountEl);

                    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(renderCharCount);
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(renderCharCount);
                    element.on(
                        'input keydown', 
                        function() {
                            renderCharCount(); //make sure it's called with no args
                        }
                    );

                    scope.$watch(attr.mdMaxlength, function(value) {
                        maxlength = value;
                        if (angular.isNumber(value) && value > 0) {
                            if (!charCountEl.parent().length) {
                                $animate.enter(
                                    charCountEl, 
                                    containerCtrl.element,
                                    angular.element(containerCtrl.element[0].lastElementChild)
                                );
                            }
                            renderCharCount();
                        } else {
                            $animate.leave(charCountEl);
                        }
                    });

                    ngModelCtrl.$validators['md-maxlength'] = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                        if (!angular.isNumber(maxlength) || maxlength < 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return (modelValue || element.val() || viewValue || '').length <= maxlength;
                    };

                    function renderCharCount(value) {
                        //Original code commented
                        debugger;
                        if(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue !== "")
                                charCountEl.text( ( element.val() || value || '' ).length + '/' + maxlength );        
                        else
                                 charCountEl.text((ngModelCtrl.$modelValue || '').length + '/' + maxlength);
                        return value;
                    }
                };
            };
            return $delegate;
        }
    );
}
```

Add this function into your module's config like below:

```
    yourModule.config(override_mdMaxlength);
```

This will correct character-count behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this bug too, after look deeper into the mdMaxlength directive, I found that we could solve this problem easily like this(according to your code):

```
    angular.module('app').controller(function($timeout){
     $scope.obj={prop:""};
     //after user input some value reset the form
     $scope.reset=function(){
        $scope.obj.prop=null;

        $scope.formName.$setPristine();
        $scope.formName.$setValidity();
        $scope.formName.$setUntouched();
        $timeout(function(){
           $scope.obj.prop="";
        })
     }

})
```

Comment: Your codepen has refactored the md-maxlength, cant do that. you can see my codepen. [http://codepen.io/likeconan/pen/revRNm](http://codepen.io/likeconan/pen/revRNm)

Comment: for it to work I had to move the formName.* functions into the timeout after the prop = ""